# change the pseudonyme with veins 3.0

Tags: veins

I installed Omnet ++ 4.6, Sumo 0.21.0 and Veins 3.0 to simulate vehicle mobility.  I read the existing tutorials of Omnet ++ in the website.
I work on anonymity and privacy in vanets but for simulation, I don't know how to proceed;
- how  to display the contents of beacons (id, speed, pos, ..) that vehivules exchange periodically.
- how can  to make vehicles use pseudonyms in place of a permanent identifier.

thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

You can use Veins 3.0 to simulate whether or not a message sent by one car is received by another car.

What this means is up to your simulation to define.

Maybe one type of message means that a VANET frame was sent using a pseudonym. Maybe another means that now is a good time to change pseudonyms. Defining meanings of message is your task when you create your simulation model.